# Optional argument after splat argument

Tags: ruby

Here is my program:

```
def calculate(*numbers, options = {})
  add(numbers)      if options[:add]
  subtract(numbers) if options[:add] == false
end

def add(*numbers)
  numbers.reduce(:+)
end

def subtract(*numbers)
  numbers.reduce(:-)
end

p calculate(1,2)
```

On line 1, it is complaining

> tests.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'
>   def calculate(*numbers, options = {})
>   ________________________________________________^
>   [Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]

I thought it might have been a problem with default values in Ruby, because before v1.9, you were required to have all default values in order - but this shouldn't be the issue because my version is

`ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14) [i386-mingw32]`

I've tried transposing the spaces all over, because ruby seems to be particular with those things when it comes to methods, but no dice.

Could it be my splat variable `*numbers` ?

Comment: You probably want to do `options: {}` for Ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks @maerics and @JorgWMittag -

When you have a splat, it reserves all arguments, which is why it was not liking my second "options" argument. I fixed this issue by changing my arguments around to -

```
def calculate(*arguments)
  options = arguments[-1].is_a?(Hash) ? arguments.pop : {}
  options[:add] = true if options.empty?
  return add(*arguments) if options[:add]
  return subtract(*arguments) if options[:subtract]
end
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this approach! It helped me find a simple and concise solution for a DSL I'm writing.

Comment: You can also shorten this method by adding the default value for the options in the hash returned by the ternary operator: `options = arguments[-1].is_a?(Hash) ? arguments.pop : {add: true}`. This allows you to remove the second line of the method.

Answer (score 11):

#### You cannot have optional parameters after a splat.

The splat means "use up all of the remaining arguments" but then you provide an optional argument, so how could the interpreter know if the last argument is part of the "numbers" splat or the optional "options"?

Answer (score 6):

You can only have mandatory arguments after the splat argument. Optional arguments must come before the splat.

A pseudo-regex for parameter lists in Ruby is something like this:

```
mand* opt* splat? mand* (mand_kw | opt_kw)* kwsplat? block?
```

Here's an example:

```
def foo(m1, m2, o1=:o1, o2=:o2, *splat, m3, m4, 
          ok1: :ok1, mk1:, mk2:, ok2: :ok2, **ksplat, &blk)
  Hash[local_variables.map {|var| [var, eval(var.to_s)] }]
end

method(:foo).arity
# => -5

method(:foo).parameters
# => [[:req, :m1], [:req, :m2], [:opt, :o1], [:opt, :o2], [:rest, :splat], 
#     [:req, :m3], [:req, :m4], [:keyreq, :mk1], [:keyreq, :mk2], 
#     [:key, :ok1], [:key, :ok2], [:keyrest, :ksplat], [:block, :blk]]

foo(1, 2, 3, 4)
# ArgumentError: missing keywords: mk1, mk2

foo(1, 2, 3, mk1: 4, mk2: 5)
# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 4+)

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, mk1: 5, mk2: 6)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: :o1, o2: :o2, splat: [], m3: 3, m4: 4, 
#      ok1: :ok1, mk1: 5, mk2: 6, ok2: :ok2, ksplat: {}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, mk1: 6, mk2: 7)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: :o2, splat: [], m3: 4, m4: 5, 
#      ok1: :ok1, mk1: 6, mk2: 7, ok2: :ok2, ksplat: {}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, mk1: 7, mk2: 8)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: 4, splat: [], m3: 5, m4: 6, 
#      ok1: :ok1, mk1: 7, mk2: 8, ok2: :ok2, ksplat: {}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, mk1: 8, mk2: 9)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: 4, splat: [5], m3: 6, m4: 7, 
#      ok1: :ok1, mk1: 8, mk2: 9, ok2: :ok2, ksplat: {}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, mk1: 9, mk2: 10)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: 4, splat: [5, 6], m3: 7, m4: 8, 
#      ok1: :ok1, mk1: 9, mk2: 10, ok2: :ok2, ksplat: {}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: 4, splat: [5, 6], m3: 7, m4: 8, 
#      ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: :ok2, ksplat: {}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: 12)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: 4, splat: [5, 6], m3: 7, m4: 8, 
#      ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: 12, ksplat: {}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: 12, k3: 13)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: 4, splat: [5, 6], m3: 7, m4: 8, 
#      ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: 12, ksplat: {k3: 13}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: 12, k3: 13, k4: 14)
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: 4, splat: [5, 6], m3: 7, m4: 8, 
#      ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: 12, ksplat: {k3: 13, k4: 14}, 
#      blk: nil }

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
      ok1: 9, ok2: 10, mk1: 11, mk2: 12, k3: 13, k4: 14) do 15 end
# => { m1: 1, m2: 2, o1: 3, o2: 4, splat: [5, 6], m3: 7, m4: 8, 
#      ok1: 9, mk1: 10, mk2: 11, ok2: 12, ksplat: {k3: 13, k4: 14}, 
#      blk: #<Proc:0xdeadbeefc00l42@(irb):15> }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any documentation for the pseudo-Regex you wrote? It looks correct, but there's not enough information in the [doc](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Default+Positional+Arguments) to be sure.

Comment: The ISO Ruby Language Specification, RubySpec, The Ruby Programming Language, Programming Ruby, the documentation, and experimentation. Lots of experimentation. Mostly the latter.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Hi. Just out of curiosity, what would be the reason for the designer to keep such a rule - "You can only have mandatory arguments after the splat argument. Optional arguments must come before the splat" ?  Is there any implementation issue to keep optional arguments after splat?

Comment: @BKS: There is no implementation issue per se. *Iff* you can come up with a rule what that means, *then* the implementation is absolutely trivial. However, the fact that you can have mandatory arguments after optional ones already confuses the heck out of people. (There are C♯ programmers that claim that it is simply impossible, for example, despite the fact that Ruby clearly proves it is.) Having two groups of optionals would probably be too confusing. But you can make a rule that is unambiguous, and the rule already tells you how to implement it:

Comment: 1) Mandatories from the left, 2) Mandatories from the right, 3) Optionals from the left, 4) Optionals from the right, 5) Splats, 6) Keywords can be interspersed arbitrarily anywhere. This would be perfectly possible to implement literally by just translating the rules into code.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Yes that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
def calculate( *numbers, add: true )
  add ? add( *numbers ) : subtract( *numbers )
end

def add *numbers; numbers.reduce( 0, :+) end

def subtract n1, n2; n1 - n2 end

calculate 1, 2 #=> 3
calculate 3, 1, add: false #=> 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out how `extract_options!` works behind Rails.

http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/09/inside-ruby-on-rails-extract_options-from-arrays/

Answer (score 1):

Actually, from **Ruby 2.0** you can accomplish this by using **keyword arguments**. If you define a method 'calculate' like this:

```
def calculate(a, *b, **options)
  return a + b.inject(0, :+) if options[:add]
  return a + b.inject(0, :-) if options[:subtract]
  return 0
end
```

Then you can call that method with this:

```
calculate(3, 4, -5, 3, -8, add: true)
```

And you'll get -3 as a result.