# Parameter passing in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following code segment

```
list=[2,4,6,8]
def tester(p1,p2,p3,*p4)
    print p1
    print '***'
    print p2
    print '***'
    print p3
    print '***'
    print p4
end
tester('first','m'=>1,'t'=>2,'w'=>3,*list)
```

Output:

```
first***w3m1t2***2***468
```

I didn't follow how `p3` gets `2` assigned. Any idea?

Comment: write deliberately ambiguous code, and you'd be surprised how it gets interpreted.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I'm aware of them. I had a problem with the editor. Will review it. In the mean time, an answer based on the conceptual content would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Your semicolons and strange indentation give very bad impression.

Comment: Whether this is grammatical or not depends on the version of Ruby. In 2.1, it seems to be ungrammatical.

Comment: For some real head-scratching play around with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17173107/2988

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the expanded list array to your method ( I know of * as splat), so it is the same as calling

```
tester('first','m'=>1,'t'=>2,'w'=>3,2,4,6,8);
```

Or put another way

```
tester('first',{'m'=>1,'t'=>2,'w'=>3}, 2, 4, 6, 8);
```

And in your method definition `*p4` does not mean the last array, it means anything left over.  So with that said I think that the first three parameters are getting assigned to p1, p2, and p3 and the remainder gets assigned to p4.  That's how p3 becomes 2.

Answer (score 1):

2 is the first element of `list` array. Ruby treats `'m'=>1,'t'=>2,'w'=>3` as one argument (`Hash` instance), so the third argument (p3) is first element of `list` array, because you pass `list` with splat operator (*), converting array into 'list' of arguments.