# Why can't I use a default value for the last argument to a function when I am using the splat operator for the initial arguments?

Tags: ruby

```
class MyClass
  def myMethod(*args, options = {})
    (...)
  end
end
```

If I start typing this in the interpreter it gives me an error when I hit enter on the second line:

> SyntaxError: unexpected '=', expecting ')'
>     def myMethod(*args, options = {})

Why can't I do this?
It works if I don't use the splat operator, ie

```
def myMethod(arg1, arg2, options = {})
```

Comment: Duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173034/optional-argument-after-splat-argument

Comment: If you were Ruby, how could you tell if the last argument is the last element of (the array) `args` (in which case the default value for `options` should apply) or a value for `options`? As a general rule, the expression of arguments is OK so long as only one interpretation is possible, even when non-trivial reasoning is needed to determine if that's the case.

Comment: Again, if the statement of arguments is ambigous to you, it will be ambiguous to Ruby, and she'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You may have noticed that reversing the order will work, as in the following code:

```
class Foo
    def bar(options = {}, *args)
        puts "Name: #{options[:name]}"
        args.each do |hobby|
            puts hobby
        end
    end
end

foo = Foo.new()

foo.bar(options = {:name => "Conan the Barbarian"}, "crocheting", "knitting", "pillaging")

> Name: Conan the Barbarian
  crocheting
  knitting
  pillaging
```

Additionally, dropping the "= {}" will make your original code work, like so:

```
def bar(*args, options)
```

The ruby interpreter attempts to add all remaining parameters to the args splat. If you're passing in bar("hello", "goodbye", "sayonara") the interpreter can't tell whether or not the final argument ("sayonara") is a part of the original splat (*args), or part of the options array.

Once you make a distinction (either by reordering the args or dropping the default hash declaration) the interpreter no longer has a problem and will run your code.

Comment: You haven't answered the question. Moreover, `Foo.new.bar("cat") #=> TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`. For extra credit, which of the above is out-of-place?

Comment: In your example you pass in a string ("cat") - the code in question is expecting an options value indexed to a specific symbol - is this an incorrect use of the options hash? As for your extra credit - do you mean which of my points is out of place?

Comment: I'll respond to your comment in a little while. For the moment, the extra credit referred to "crocheting, knitting, pillaging".

Comment: Crocheting of course - real Barbarians knit.

Comment: The point of the question is how `options` can be made optional when there is a splatted argument. The answer is that it can't. Your answer would only work if `Foo.new.bar("cat")` caused `option` to equal `{}` and  `args` to equal `["cat"]`. Being first in the list of arguments, and no required arguments, `options` will be set to `"cat"` (and `args` to `[]`) and `"cat"[:name]` raises the exception.  The downvote was mine. (Sorry.)