# Why I cannot use a default argument at the right of a sponge argument?

Tags: ruby

When I ran this on ruby 2.3.1p112:

```
def test(x, *y, z = 1)
    puts x, y, z
end
```

I got this message:

```
(repl):1: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'
def test(x, *y, z = 1)
```

By the other hand, when I cahnge the position of the parameters y and z it works.

```
def test(x, z = 1, *y)
    puts x, y, z
end
```

Why is not possible to use this optional parameter on the right of the sponge argument?

live code: https://repl.it/CaXU/2

Note: This question is different from [Optional argument after splat argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173034/optional-argument-after-splat-argument) because that question ask about a hash optional parameter while this one ask for a simple non-hash optional paramenter. When it is an optional hash argument there is no way to know how many arguments assign to the hash and to the sponge argument. Although, in the case of an optional parameter that is not a hash, would make sense to assign one element to the optional parameter and the rest to the sponge argument.

Comment: We need more information. What version of Ruby are you running? Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages and "[mcve]".

Comment: Thanks @theTinMan. I modified the question adding the ruby version and a live code link.

Comment: I think you mean "splat," although "sponge" is not without its appeal.

Comment: @Jordan: I think the operator is called splat operator, but the whole argument is called sponge argument.

Comment: @CarlosSadhuRojasÑiquen Perhaps in other programming languages, but that's not a term familiar to Rubyists.

Comment: @Jordan: Thanks for the comments. The `sponge argument` is the terminology David A. Black uses on The Well Grounded Rubyist book. Before read that book I also never saw that terminology, but doing a google search looks like that terminology is in use.

Comment: That is the way it is documented as behaving. Not sure what sort of answer you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby does not allow ambiguity. Such cases are syntactically excluded. When you pass two arguments, how would it know whether the second argument should be part of y, with nothing passed for z, or y should be empty, z being the second argument?

Comment: I thought the same. But when I change the order of the y and z parameters it works fine, even it could look like have the same ambiguity. I updated the original question with this information.