# Why am I getting an "Unexpected *" error when using the * (asterisk) operator as a method parameter?

Tags: ruby

I'm learning Ruby at the moment and I came across this peculiar situation.

When I run the following code, I get the output shown further below.

**Working Code:**

```
def hello(a,b=1,*c,d,e,f)
  p a,b,c,d,e,f
end

hello(1,2,3,4,5)
```

**Working Code Output:**

```
1
2
[]
3
4
5
```

However, upon editing the code so that the parameter 'e' is the catch all parameter, I get the error shown further below.

**Failing Code:**

```
def hello(a,b=1,c,d,*e,f)
    p a,b,c,d,e,f
end

hello(1,2,3,4,5)
```

**Failing Code Output:**

```
a.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected *
def hello(a,b=1,c,d,*e,f)
                     ^
a.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '='
a.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

I'm using ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) on Ubuntu.

I'm interested in knowing why the second snippet of code fails.

**Edit:**

The following code fails as well.

```
def hello(a,b=1,c,d,e,*f)
    p a,b,c,d,e,f
end

hello(1,2,3,4,5)
```

And I get a similar error

```
a.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected *
def hello(a,b=1,c,d,e,*f)
                       ^
a.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

Comment: Using a splat operator not at the end doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: True. It's not readable, but it is possible to parse it though, and Ruby does it in certain cases.

Comment: @fl00r I tried the following method definition and I get the same error. def hello(a,b=1,c,d,e,*f)

Answer (score 5):

The relevant documentation is [here](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Default+Positional+Arguments) and here's a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173034/optional-argument-after-splat-argument).
They don't seem to cover all cases though.

Here's what I could gather :

- no more than one splat operator (`*args`) can be used.
- multiple default arguments can be used (`a=1, b=2`).
- default arguments must be to the left of the splat operator.
- multiple default arguments must come directly one after the other.
- if default arguments and splat operator are used, the default arguments must come right before the splat operator.
- if the above rules are followed, default arguments and splat operator can be anywhere in the arguments list.

For readability, it might be a good idea to :

- put the splat operator as the last argument
- avoid putting default arguments in the middle

Here are valid method definitions :

```
def  hello(a = 1, b)            ;end
def  hello(a, b = 2)            ;end
def  hello(a = 1, b = 2)        ;end
def  hello(a = 1, b = 2, c)     ;end
def  hello(a, b = 2, c = 3)     ;end
def  hello(a, b = 2, *c)        ;end
def  hello(a, b = 2, *c, d)     ;end
def  hello(a = 1, b = 2, *c, d) ;end
```

For your second example, this syntax would be fine :

```
def hello(a,b,c,d=1,*e,f)
    p a,b,c,d,e,f
end
```

For a more complete example with block and keyword arguments, see @JörgWMittag's excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17173107/6419007).

Comment: Thanks Eric. That was my understanding as well. I am very puzzled that the second case does not work for me.

Comment: @Steve In your second example, when passing exactly 5 arguments, it's not clear whether `b` should be passed as `1` or your second argument. To avoid these ambiguities, Ruby enforces these stricter rules.

Comment: Thanks @HolgerJust. My code fails the following rule that Eric mentioned. **If default arguments and splat operator are used, the default arguments must come right before the splat operator.** If I follow this rule, the code works fine.

Comment: @HolgerJust: The second method is no more ambiguous than the first one. Both are weird and shouldn't be used IMHO. The first one is accepted by Ruby, the other not.