# Syntax error: initialization with splat operator and empty hash

Tags: ruby, hash, syntax, splat

#### I have the following code that as far as I know should work correctly but doesn't:

```
def calculate( *nums, options = {} ) //errors out here on equals sign
  if options.empty
    return add(nums)
  elsif options[:subtract]
    return substract(nums)
  elsif options[:add]
    return add(nums)
  end
end
```

#### Error:

> class: SyntaxError
> message: /opt/eval-server/eval-server/app/models/eval_spec_runner.rb:5: syntax
> error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'
> def calculate( *nums, options = {} )                              ^
> backtrace: RubyMonk:18:in `eval'

Comment: I am pretty sure no one can explain this better than @JörgWMittag did on [This SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17173107/1978251). BTW you could not define options in the signature and instead use something like `options = nums.last.is_a?(Hash) ? nums.pop : {}` in the body of your method.

Comment: That post solves this one. I cannot delete this post because it is flagged by a moderator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A splat argument must be the last argument of your method.

Comment: Not necessarily true [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173034/optional-argument-after-splat-argument/17173107#17173107)

Comment: I found that 1.8 and 1.9+ have differences for this standard. Hmm...

Comment: @jStaff: Yes. 1.9 relaxed some rules. 2.0 added optional keyword parameters. 2.1 added mandatory keyword parameters.